# os.path doesn't seem to work on Windows 8

Tags: python, windows-8, jython, os.path

One of the people using a Jython script I wrote had the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'path'
```

After investigation, it turns out that the error occurs when the code runs `os.path`.
Actually, I found out that `os.path` is not defined on its system (Windows 8) and more precisely there's no module `ntpath`.

The following command, supposed to list all the modules dealing with path:

```
import sys
print filter(lambda x: "path" in x, sys.modules)
```

returns an empty list.

Does anybody know how to fix this issue? Is it a "normal" or known behaviour on Windows 8 or it's really specific the version of this user.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does `import os; print os.__file__` show?

Answer (score 1):

`sys.modules` lists all *imported* modules, not available ones.

The reason why `os.path` is not working for you is probably because you have a file in your current directory called `os.py`, which is hiding the version from the stdlib.